# Six-month peak-season running average

Tags: r

I'm trying to implement [this](https://apps.who.int/iris/handle/10665/345329):

> The recommendation is a peak season ozone AQG level of 60 μg/m3
> (the average of daily maximum 8-hour mean ozone concentrations).
> The peak season is defined as the six consecutive months of the year
> with the highest six-month running-average ozone concentration.
> In regions away from the equator, this period will typically be in the
> warm season within a single calendar year (northern hemisphere)
> or spanning two calendar years (southern hemisphere). Close to
> the equator, such clear seasonal patterns may not be obvious, but a
> running-average six-month peak season will usually be identifiable
> from existing monitoring or modelling data.

I have:

```
# A tibble: 300 × 2
   date                value
   <dttm>              <dbl>
 1 1997-01-01 00:00:00 NA   
 2 1997-02-01 00:00:00 NA   
 3 1997-03-01 00:00:00 NA   
 4 1997-04-01 00:00:00 30.2 
 5 1997-05-01 00:00:00 20.9 
 6 1997-06-01 00:00:00 10.1 
 7 1997-07-01 00:00:00  9.40
 8 1997-08-01 00:00:00 22.4 
 9 1997-09-01 00:00:00 26.2 
10 1997-10-01 00:00:00 32.9 
# … with 290 more rows
```

Every year is complete (with or without NA). I found the peaks by "findpeaks" from pracma package, and get:

```
peaks = findpeaks(mda8_omit$value, minpeakdistance = 6, 
                  minpeakheight = mean(mda8_omit$value))
```

[image: peaks in series]

How do i optimize to get the best six month by peak? For northern hemisphere is easier because the peaks is within a yer (summer) but in the southern hemisphere is split in two years and peaks may change depending on latitude. Any ideas on how to continue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that

- we only use windows with 6 consecutive months of data
- the year that a window falls is determined by the last month of the window
- we compare all such windows, at most 12, within each calendar year

Calculate the rolling mean and then grouping by year take the row with the largest rolling mean within year.  This row is the last month of the 6 month window.  The input is shown reproducibly in the Note at the end.

```
library(dplyr)
library(zoo)

DF %>%
  mutate(date = as.yearmon(date), 
         peakmean = rollapplyr(value, 6, mean, fill = NA)) %>%
  group_by(year = as.integer(date)) %>%
  slice_max(peakmean) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-year)
## # A tibble: 1 × 3
##   date      value peakmean
##   <yearmon> <dbl>    <dbl>
## 1 Oct 1997   32.9     20.3
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "date                value
 1 1997-01-01T00:00:00 NA   
 2 1997-02-01T00:00:00 NA   
 3 1997-03-01T00:00:00 NA   
 4 1997-04-01T00:00:00 30.2 
 5 1997-05-01T00:00:00 20.9 
 6 1997-06-01T00:00:00 10.1 
 7 1997-07-01T00:00:00  9.40
 8 1997-08-01T00:00:00 22.4 
 9 1997-09-01T00:00:00 26.2 
10 1997-10-01T00:00:00 32.9"

DF <- read.table(text = Lines)
```